# Telegram Chat Bot in google app script with if

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, telegram-bot

I have setup an telegram chat bot, I need push messenger to group chat when value at col10 equal "Hoàn Thành", I set trigger for onEdit(e) that when value in column J change, it will push messenger success, but I don't know how to make the script exactly get value in col J is "Hoàn Thành".

Please edit it for me

```
// 2. Trigger edit
function onEdit(e) {
  var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("Task")
    .getRange("A2:K"); // vùng check trigger
  var row = e.range.getRow(); // lấy dòng đang bị edit
  var col = e.range.getColumn(); // lấy cột đang bị edit

  // 2.1 set cột đang bị edit để thực thi trigger or có thể để nguyên vùng 'A2:J', ở đây đang set cột 10 "Trạng thái CV"
  if (
    col >= myRange.getColumn() && // cột đang bị edit >= cột đầu tiên của  chứa dữ liệu
    col <= myRange.getLastColumn() && // cột đang bị edit <= cột cuối cùng của  chứa dữ liệu
    row >= myRange.getRow() &&  // dòng đang bị edit >= dòng đầu tiên của  chứa dữ liệu
    row <= myRange.getLastRow() // dòng đang bị edit <= dòng cuối cùng của  chứa dữ liệu
  ) {
    if (col == 11) {
      var data_info = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
        .getRange(row, 1, 1, 11)
        .getValues();

      data_info[0][0] != "" ? sendTelegramNotification(data_info) : "";
      //sent_Mail(data_info)
    }
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

// 3. Gửi thông báo đến telegram.
function sendTelegramNotification(data) {
 
  var ref = "";
  ref += "&#x1F4DD   <strong> ĐỀ NGHỊ PHÊ DUYỆT CÔNG VIỆC</strong> \n";
  ref += "------------------------------------------------------------- \n  \n";
  ref +="<code> &#x1F4C5 " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss") + "</code> \n \n ";
  ref += "<em> &#x1F538 Huyền Phương đã làm xong công việc</em>:  <code>" + data[0][1] + "</code> \n";
  ref += "&#x2705 anh Trung vào kiểm tra ngay nhé &#x2705 \n\n";
  ref += "------------------------------------------------------------ ";

  var body = ref;

  var link_fetch =
    "https://api.telegram.org/bot" +
    botSecret +
    "/sendMessage?text=" +
    encodeURIComponent(body) +
    "&chat_id=" +
    chatId +
    "&parse_mode=HTML";

  // Thực thi gửi tin nhắn tới tele
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(link_fetch);
}
```

Comment: What is the sheet name that this function is supposed to run in.

Comment: the sheet name is "Task"